# What is the XPath to search for multiple attributes and elements?

Tags: c#, xpath, .net-4.5

I have some XML which I need to search for sections where fields match a certain criteria. I am trying to use XPath but am not sure how to look for two "field" sections. Here is the XPath that finds two items:

```
/importJob/links/link/field[@name='ModuleId' and @value='ab6f15c7-bb68-4243-8815-02818c6dbbee']"
```

But if I try this, it doesn't find any items:

```
/importJob/links/link/field[@name='ModuleId' and @value='ab6f15c7-bb68-4243-8815-02818c6dbbee' and @name='SystemId' and @value='850fd5eb-0985-4169-bce9-c62ad0335c5f']"
```

Here is the source XML:

```
<importJob>
  <links>
    <link linkId="00cb3dca-ffd6-4a90-b690-01e99913708d" LastModifiedDate_UTC="2012-10-24T23:28:00">
      <field name="ModuleId" value="ab6f15c7-bb68-4243-8815-02818c6dbbee" />
      <field name="SystemId" value="850fd5eb-0985-4169-bce9-c62ad0335c5f" />
    </link>
    <link linkId="00cb3dca-ffd6-4a90-b690-01e99913708d" LastModifiedDate_UTC="2012-10-24T23:28:00">
      <field name="ModuleId" value="ab6f15c7-bb68-4243-8815-02818c6dbbee" />
      <field name="SystemId" value="3c922537-0457-4fc5-a282-ee5a5f7084f2" />
    </link>
    <link linkId="00cb3dca-ffd6-4a90-b690-01e99913708d" LastModifiedDate_UTC="2012-10-24T23:28:00">
      <field name="ModuleId" value="b77d692a-1f89-4abb-8af2-0c955364107a" />
      <field name="SystemId" value="850fd5eb-0985-4169-bce9-c62ad0335c5f" />
    </link>
    <link linkId="00cb3dca-ffd6-4a90-b690-01e99913708d" LastModifiedDate_UTC="2012-10-24T23:28:00">
      <field name="ModuleId" value="b77d692a-1f89-4abb-8af2-0c955364107a" />
      <field name="SystemId" value="3c922537-0457-4fc5-a282-ee5a5f7084f2" />
    </link>
  </links>    
</importJob>
```

Can someone help by telling me if what I need to do is possible with XPath and if it is, what would be the correct XPath command. In the Live code this will be created dynamically and there may be one or several "field" elements. I can program this but need the XPath command first.

EDIT 1 -------------------------

My question could be clearer so I'm adding some more details here.

I need to return one or more "link" sections where all the "name" and "value" attributes match the XPath command. So based on my sample xml I need to create an XPath command that will return the first "link" section. The ModuleId is the same in the first two "link" sections so that is why the command must use multiple "field" parts so that it returns only the first "link" section. In my attempt at creating an XPath command (second one above) you can see that it has two "name" and two "value" parts. I was hoping this would find the first "link" section.

EDIT 2 -------------------------

I am now using this XPath command and it appears to work. I needed to use some brackets and to move the "field" part so that it would return the link section.

```
/importJob/links/link[(field/@name='SystemId' and field/@value='850fd5eb-0985-4169-bce9-c62ad0335c5f') and (field/@name='ModuleId' and field/@value='ab6f15c7-bb68-4243-8815-02818c6dbbee')]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to select both module and system fields, then use OR

```
"/importJob/links/link/field[(@name='ModuleId' and @value='ab6f15c7-bb68-4243-8815-02818c6dbbee') or (@name='SystemId' and @value='850fd5eb-0985-4169-bce9-c62ad0335c5f')]";
```

That gives:

```
<field name="ModuleId" value="ab6f15c7-bb68-4243-8815-02818c6dbbee" />
<field name="SystemId" value="850fd5eb-0985-4169-bce9-c62ad0335c5f" />
<field name="ModuleId" value="ab6f15c7-bb68-4243-8815-02818c6dbbee" />
<field name="SystemId" value="850fd5eb-0985-4169-bce9-c62ad0335c5f" />
```

Otherwise you are trying to find field which is module AND system at same time. Thus you don't have such fields, nothing is returned.

EDIT: You can use following xpath with nested predicates to get `link` elements which have both fields with conditions you'll provide

```
var xpath = "//link[field[@name='ModuleId' and @value='ab6f15c7-bb68-4243-8815-02818c6dbbee'] and field[@name='SystemId' and @value='850fd5eb-0985-4169-bce9-c62ad0335c5f']]";
```

Comment: I have updated my question as I don't think it was clear what I was trying to achieve. I will try the example you have given to see if I can make it work with what I need.

Comment: @Retrocoder so, you want `link` elements instead of `field` elements, which you was selecting in your code?

Comment: I want the link section based on its field values. I think I have managed to do it based on your example. I will place it in the original question.

Comment: The XPath command that seems to work is under "Edit 3" in my original question. Thanks to your help I managed to put it all together. Many thanks.

Comment: @Retrocoder you can use nested predicates (i.e. `[]` conditions) to check fields for links, see my edit